# bash or shell script remove subdirectories but keep all nested data

Tags: bash, sh

I have a deeply nested folder structure that and I want to reduce the nesting by two levels by removing the sub-directories completely, but bringing all the data under them outside to the parent folder
Example1:
path:

```
folder1/folder2/id=123/date_from=2022-10-12/date_to=2023-10-12/sys_date_from=12%1A22%3A19.489/sys_date_to=8888-12-31 23%3A59%3A59.999/slice=watermelon/binary_file_name.parquet
```

path I want after removing level two levels-

```
folder1/folder2/id=123/date_from=2022-10-12/sys_date_to=8888-12-31 23%3A59%3A59.999/slice=watermelon/binary_file_name.parquet
```

Here I have removed the two level date_to=2023-10-12 and sys_date_from=12%1A22%3A19.489 from the path, but no data is lost. Whatever was under them I got that outside to their parent folder.

The folde2 and the value after equal to(=) in  the nested folders keep changing.

For example I can also have:

```
folder1/folder10/id=456/date_from=2021-04-01/date_to=2022-03-11/sys_date_from=08%8G22%3B19.909/sys_date_to=8888-12-31 23%3A59%3A59.999/slice=apple/binary_file_name2.parquet
```

after removing the date_to and sys_date_from folders my file struction should look like this:

```
folder1/folder10/id=456/date_from=2021-04-01/sys_date_to=8888-12-31 23%3A59%3A59.999/slice=apple/binary_file_name2.parquet
```

I looked at getting this wokring via the find command, but struggling to get anything coherent. How do I do this via bash command or shell scripting?
I want to do this in an automated fashion to all folders under folder1. Could be as many as ten folders under folder1.

Comment: Use the `find` command to find all the files in the directory hierarchy. Use `-exec mv` to move them to the desired target directory. Then use `rm -r` to remove the directories you don't want.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any duplicate filenames, since they'll overwrite each other when you move them all into a single directory.

Comment: First make a backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
(
    shopt -s dotglob nullglob
    for top in folder1/folder*/id=*/date_from=* ; do
        pushd "$top"
        for sub in date_to=*/sys_date_from=* ; do
            mv "$sub"/* .
            rmdir "$sub" "${sub%/*}"
        done
        popd
    done
)
```

- enable `nullglob` so globs matching nothing return nothing - makes glob expansion return a (possibly-empty) list of paths that all exist (by default, `x*` as output could be an actual path (character "x" followed by literal asterisk), or it might indicate a glob expansion failure)
- enable `dotglob` so that during glob expansion, a leading `*` in a path segment will match names that start with `.`
- loop over list of all paths generated by expanding the first glob (`top`)

  - `pushd`(`popd`) - change directory into(out of) `top` to allow use of shorter relative paths in inner loop
  - loop over list of paths generated by expanding the second glob (`sub`) (relative to directory `top`)

    - move all contents of `sub` to current directory (ie. `top`)
    - delete `sub` and its parent - `${sub%/*}` strips the final path element

The surrounding parentheses `(` ... `)` aren't really needed; they localise the `shopt` changes if the program is extended, and insulate code appended after them from `pushd`/`popd` failure (which should be checked). They also allow testing the code by cut&paste to an interactive shell without permanently changing its settings.

---

Assumes `date_to=2023-10-12` **only** contains `sys_date_from=12%1A22%3A19.489`; it can't be deleted if it isn't empty.

If `date_to=2023-10-12` contains multiple `sys_date_from=[...]` subdirectories, it will eventually get deleted, but `rmdir` will give error messages. These can be avoided by nesting another level. eg: `for sub1 in date_to=*; do for sub2 in "$sub1"/sys_date_from=*; ...`

Also assumes file permissions allow the `pushd` and `mv` - adding appropriate error-checking is advisable.

Also add checks for overwriting unless the subdirectory contents are guaranteed to have unique names when moved.

Comment: What's with the parentheses? The options won't leak outside of the script anyway.

Comment: @tripleee mainly in case the lines are cut&pasted interactively, as I often do, or if the script is extended with other code later. yes, the parentheses are redundant as shown.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it worked, but it was difficult to understand without any explanation. Didn't get a chance to try @tripleee 's asnwer but I actually liked that he explained it well

Comment: @user2441441 fair point. it's always hard to know what someone else will find obvious (or not). which part needs explanation? the shopt settings? for loops? globbing? parameter expansion?

Comment: - shopt -s dotglob nullglob -> what it does?
 - for top in folder1/folder*/id=*/date_from=* ; do -> loops through what?
- pushd "$top" -> what pushd does and why we are pushing it?
- popd -> why we are popping this?
- what does inner loop do at high level? - Eg: Will move subfolder under date_to=*/sys_date_from=*  to current directory and then remove the subfolder 
- what "${sub%/*}" does?
-just answering since you asked, appreciate the answer, thank you

Comment: @user2441441 any better?

Comment: yes! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
find . -depth -type d \( -name 'sys_date_from=*' -o -name 'date_to=*' \) \
    -execdir sh -c 'mv "$1"/* . && rmdir "$1"' _ {} \;
```

The `-depth` option says to start from the lowest directories and traverse backwards, to avoid attempting to visit something after a parent directory was renamed. `-execdir` runs in the directory where `find` found something, with the bare file or directory name as input in `{}`. We need to wrap the commands in `sh -c` so that the expression only gets evaluated by the shell when `find` runs it, not when you run `find`. The rest should be fairly obvious I hope.

You might want to add some options to the `mv` command to avoid clobbering existing files with the same names; unfortunately, MacOS only offers `mv -n` to refuse overwriting (and even that is more than POSIX `mv` provides), while GNU `mv` has options to rename the file if merely moving it would overwrite an existing file.